# Why doesn't nohup work on a specific process

Tags: linux, nohup

For what reason(s) would nohup not work on a specific in-house developed process?

I'm using it as follows:

> /usr/bin/nohup process_a &

I can close the terminal where it was executed and see that it is still running via ps. However, after logging out and back in again the process is no longer running.

I can run the same nohup command on a different in-house developed process_b and logging out and back in does not end the process. It is still running.

I'm wondering what could be "special" about process_a such that it does not survive logging out and back in again. Both process a and b open a TCP server socket and also have open file descriptors for logging.

I've tried using bash, tcsh, and zsh shells, all with the same results.

For what reason(s) would one process running under nohup survive logging out/in and another would not? I'm assuming there's something in the code that the developers can change.

We're running RHEL 6 in a fairly restrictive environment (screen, tmux, etc. are not available alternatives).

UPDATE:

process_a survives the following

> kill -s HUP PID

so SIGHUP appears to be successfully handled via nohup in this instance.
It still dies at logout though.

Comment: Is there any use of /dev/tty in process_a?

Comment: No explicit use of /dev/tty by the process

Comment: @icarus: It wouldn’t have to be `/dev/tty`, would it? A reference to stdout or stderr could cause a problem, right? … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … RudolfSchmidt: What happens if you do `nohup process_a > /dev/null 2>&1`, and then logout and login again?

Comment: G-Man: logout/login = it dies.  It still survives the kill -HUP though.  I verified that fd's 0, 1, and 2 all point to /dev/null in /proc/PID/fd.

Comment: @G-ManSays'ReinstateMonica' the versions of nohup that I know about redirect stdout and stderr to the file `nohup.out` if they are still connected to the terminal.

Comment: @RudolfSchmidt you checked /proc/XXX/fd/{0,1,2}  - are there any more pointing to tty devices?

Comment: @icarus : fd 3 is pointing to a log file, something.txt ; fd's 4 and 5 are sockets.

Comment: It would be interesting to see if the process dies immediately on logout or some time later. Does `disown` help?

Comment: @icarus: D’oh!  Of course you’re right.  Checking ```/proc/PID/fd``` is a good idea.

Comment: @icarus : executed nohup process_a > /dev/null 2>&1 & then executed disown when the command line came back.  It did not survive.  I verified, via another box, that the process dies the moment I log out.

Comment: OK, lets blame systemd and/or pam! As you are in a restricted environment this is going to be tricky. Do you have `gdb` available? If so could you log in twice. In one terminal do the nohup process_a, then find the PID. In the second widow run `gdb PID`, then logout in the first window and see if gdb tells you that the process was killed?

Comment: First, thanks to you both for spending your time helping with this issue.  It is much appreciated.  I believe it might be related to the fact that it is a Motif based executable that is running in "non-GUI" mode.  If it is dependent on the X Windows server, even though the GUI is not realized, then logging out would kill the process, right?  I'm going to experiment with some small executables of my own, and will update accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The specific reason that this process did not survive log out/in while running under nohup was that it utilized Motif.  Even though in our environment for this process the GUI was not being invoked/realized, the code ultimately used XtAppMainLoop in its main() (c code).  Perhaps the Motif libraries do something with the SIGNALS.

Additional reasons, as suggested in the other answers/comments:

The process explicitly catches/resets SIGHUP

The process utilizes tty device(s)

Answer (score 2):

If the code of process_a explicitly catches SIGHUP (the hangup signal)
or resets it to the default handler (i.e., none; i.e., exit),
that would explain the behavior you are seeing. 
Ask the developers to search the code for `SIGHUP` and see what it is doing.

You might be able to diagnose this better
if you can run `strace` on the program,
but, since you have “a fairly restrictive environment”,
`strace` probably isn’t available. 
You may be able to test more quickly and generate more actionable forensics
if you

1. Start the process (`nohup process_a &`),
2. note the PID that is reported,
3. wait a few seconds or minutes,
4. verify that the process is running with the known PID (e.g., with `ps`),
5. do `kill -HUP PID`,
6. recheck the process, and maybe
7. wait a few seconds or minutes and recheck the process again.

Comment: The code base does not do anything with SIGHUP.

Comment: The process survives kill -HUP PID.  strace is not available currently, but I am going to request it.  Thanks for the suggestions.